# swift - order of functions - which code runs when?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have an issue with my code and I think it could be related to the order in which code is called.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

private var tasks = [Task]()

override func willActivate() {
    let taskUrl = "http://myjsonurl.com"
    downloadJsonTask(url: taskUrl)
    print(tasks.count) // EMPTY
    super.willActivate()
}

func downloadJsonTask(url: String) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, urlResponse, error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("something is wrong")
            return
        }

        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedTasks = try decoder.decode(Tasks.self, from: data)
            self.tasks = downloadedTasks.tasks
            print(downloadedTasks.tasks.count) //4

        } catch {
            print("somehting went wrong after downloading")
        }

    }.resume()
}
}
```

I'm defining the `private var tasks` and fill it with the `downloadJsonTask` function but after the function ran the `print(tasks.count)` gives 0.
When I call `print(downloadedTasks.tasks.count)` it gives 4.

I think that in sequence of time the tasks variable is empty when I print it and it is filled later on.

Comment: `dataTask(with:)` in WatchKit, macOS and iOS is asynchrone. The `guard let data = data,` ie the completion of the method is called whenever you got the the result of the request. I can differs (bad connection etc) and is async to avoid blocking the current thread (and if it's the main one, that's all your UI that is blocked)

Comment: Unrelated but **never ever** print pointless literal strings like `"something is wrong"` when an `error` occurred. That's pretty silly. Print the `error` instance to get a meaningful error description.

Comment: @Larme I'm still about to learn swift and my code is written after reading tutorials. I'm still to new to transfer your comment to a solution. I think doing asynchrone requests is correct and it is my issue as the same time. If it was not asynchrone I was able to have the `print(tasks.count)` with 4, as well. But it should be asynchrone, so what is your proposed solution for me in detail?
@vadian same here. I'm to new to transfer year answer in code. I googled and found `catch let error` and then `print(error)`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: `catch let error` is redundant. Just `print(error)`. In your code put the things you want to do after the data has been received **into** the completion handler (replacing the *working* print line).

Comment: Look for "Swift + Async + Closure" to know how manage Asynchrone. In a nutshell, `dataTask(with:)` use a closure to manage it, do the same by creating a closure on your method that will be called when the `URLSession` one will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to print number of tasks in willActivate(), function downloadJsonTask(url: String) hasn't been completed yet, so you have empty array because tasks haven't been set yet.

You should add completion handler to downloadJsonTask just like this:

*(don't forget to pass completion as parameter of function)*

```
func downloadJsonTask(url: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, urlResponse, error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("something is wrong")
            completion()
            return
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedTasks = try decoder.decode(Tasks.self, from: data)
            self.tasks = downloadedTasks.tasks
            print(downloadedTasks.tasks.count) //4
        } catch {
            print("something went wrong after downloading")
        }
        completion() // This is moment when code which you write inside closure get executed

    }.resume()
}
```

In your willActivate() use this function like this:

```
downloadJsonTask(url: taskUrl) { 
    print(tasks.count)
}
```

So that means when you get your data, your code inside curly braces will get executed.

Comment: It says `Use of unresolved identifier 'completion'; did you mean 'Collection'?`

Comment: You have to pass completion: @escaping () -> Void as parameter of downloadJsonTask function

Answer (score 0):

You’re correct in your assumption that `tasks` has not yet been assigned a value when it’s first printed.

The thing is network requests are performed asynchronously. It means that iOS does not wait until `downloadJsonTask(url:)` is finished but continues executing the code right away (i.e. it calls `print(tasks.count)` immediately after the network request *started*, without waiting for it to produce any results).

The piece of code inside brackets after `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:)` is called a **completion handler**. This code gets executed once the network request is competed (hence the name). The `tasks` variable is assigned a value only when the request is finished. You can make sure it works by adding `print(self.tasks.count)` after `self.tasks = downloadedTasks.tasks`:

```
self.tasks = downloadedTasks.tasks
print(self.tasks)
print(downloadedTasks.tasks.count)
```

Comment: Thank you. But still, how can I access the variable within `willActivate()`? My example is just print the count but in my real app I want to fill a table view and so on.

Comment: You can add a completion handler to `downloadJsonTask(url:)` and make it `@escaping` (the function declaration will look like `func downloadJsonTask(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`. After `self.tasks = downloadedTasks.tasks`, call `completion()`. This will effectively pass the completion handler on from `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:)` to `downloadJsonTask(url:)`.

If you’d like the results to be displayed in a table view, you’d have to refresh the table view once the network request is finished.

Comment: @T.Karter *how can I access the variable within willActivate()*? Not at all. Once again: Put the code to populate the table view in the completion handler of `dataTask`. An additional completion handler is actually not needed.

Comment: That is true. You don’t necessarily need another completion handler. However, putting all the code in one place makes it look messy.